# .net My.Settings.Upgrade() suddenly behaving differently

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2022

I have a .net (framework 4.8) WPF app that for years has relied on the following line of code:

```
My.Settings.Upgrade()
```

to help upgrade its settings between versions.  It even continued to work when I went from a non strongly named app to a strongly named app.

In the past a settings file contents looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <userSettings>
        <Push2Run.MySettings>
            <setting name="NextVersionCheckDate" serializeAs="String">
                <value>2023-02-12</value>
            </setting>

               ... many settings removed ...

            <setting name="MainWindowSize" serializeAs="String">
                <value>700, 450</value>
            </setting>
        </Push2Run.MySettings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

and the new settings file would be created, following the same pattern, in a new folder with the new version number under the same parent folder as the previous version's setting file with all the old values carried forward.

However, now what is happening, is the new setting file is being created with the right name in the right folder but with an unexpected internal format that my program does not interpret.

The new format looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings">
            <section name="Push2Run.My.MySettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <Push2Run.My.MySettings>
            <setting name="NextVersionCheckDate" serializeAs="String">
                <value>2023-02-12</value>
            </setting>
            
             ... many settings removed ...
         
            <setting name="MainWindowSize" serializeAs="String">
                <value>700, 450</value>
            </setting>
        </Push2Run.My.MySettings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Also, the content of the new upgraded settings file does not contain the all old setting values carried forward (as it had always had in the past).

I believe I have a manual workaround for this, but it's real kludge and I don't much like it - basically taking the settings from the old file and programmatically merging them into the new file.

The last time I released a version of this program, early October 2022, I did not have this problem.  However, I'm not sure what has changed since then other than Visual Studio (2022) itself has had some upgrades along the way.

I have triple and quadruple checked, and it is not a code change on my end.

Any insights around what may have caused this or how to best correct for it would be much appreciated.

EDIT: as this problem was getting in the way of a release, and as I didn't get any feedback here, I decided to go ahead with a hand crafted  Kludge solution.  I've also posted the problem here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/net-MySettingsUpgrade-suddenly-beha/10271937
for Microsoft to look at.